# Sed command and unknown patterns found online

Tags: sed

I need help with the command sed, in particular with the following expression:

```
sed -e 's/*(.*)//;s/>.*//;s/.*[:<]*//'
```

I know that *s/pattern/replacement/* means that a *pattern* is replaced by a *replacement* and when there is no *replacement* it means that the *pattern* is just removed (is that correct?). Also, I have seen somewhere that ".*" matches anything greedy and that "[ ]" is a match of any of whatever its content is....I think.

Can anybody help please? What do the patterns `*(.*)` or `>.*` or `.*[:<]*` mean?

Comment: Some clarification: I need to process a file containing emails concatenated as a result of a fetchmail retrieval. What I need to do is extracting the email addresses to be then matched to an external text file listing known email addresses. The "sed" part of my script should get rid of anything before and after company_name@somedomain....
$ cat file | grep From: 
(NEW LINE) From: Sender1 <sender.one@domain1>
(NL)From: Sender2 <sender.two@domain2>
 (NL)h=Date:From:To:Subject:References:From:Subject;
(NL)should just become the following list
(NL)sender.one@domain1
(NL)sender.two@domain2

Comment: I have resolved the problem. Check my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By `cat file | grep From:` and piping the output into the above `sed` expression, I could see that nothing came out of it. So I decided to look into the code itself. I knew that `.*` matches anything greedy and that `/ //` are separators (from-to), I noticed that the final block, `s/.*[:<]*//`, did nothing. So I took it away. I also noticed that the second block, `s/>.*//`, was taking the final ">" away from `From: Name Surname <name.surname@somedomain>`, so I worked on the first block, `s/*(.*)//`, to make it so that it would erase the initial "<" and whatever is before it. I ended up with the expression `sed -e 's/.*<//;s/>.*//'` that transforms `From: Name Surname <name.surname@somedomain>` into `name.surname@somedomain`.