# Configure procmail to match an external email address list when filtering emails

Tags: email, sed, procmail

My fetchmail scripts retrieves emails from an email box and puts them into a file, called *mario*, and dumps it into my `/var/mail/` folder. I am trying to set up a *procmail* script to process *mario*; by processing, this is what I mean: the *procmail* script should filter against an external text file (*fromlist*) containing a list of known email addresses. Once there is a match `mario/fromlist`, the message is pulled out from *mario* and stored into my local `nbox/` folder.

Online, I found a piece of code, including a recipe, that I have entered into my *procmail* control file (`.procmailrc`) but it doesn't seem to be working. This is the code:

```
FROMFL=$MAIL/fromlist

FROMLS=formail -xFrom: | sed -e 's/*(.*)//;s/>.*//;s/.*[:]*//'`

:0

* ? fgrep -xi $FROMLS $FROMFL

$MAIL/inbox
```

I think I have addressed the `sed` (see my question [Sed command and unknown patterns found online](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50878491)), but I still haven't been able to address the *formail* and *fgrep* parts. So when I run the *procmail* script, the logs I obtain are:

```
$ mailstat var/log/procmail.log
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open fgrep
/bin/sh: 1: grep: not found
/bin/sh: 1: sed: not found
/home/user/var/mail/reginbox/
procmail: [6880] Sat Jun 16 16:57:32 2018
procmail: Acquiring kernel-lock
procmail: Assigning "FROMFL=/home/user/var/mail/fromlist"
procmail: Assigning "FROMLS="
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/home/user/var/mail/reginbox/msg.XXX"
procmail: Assigning "SHELL=/bin/sh"
procmail: Executing "fgrep,-xi,/home/user/var/mail/fromlist"
procmail: Executing "formail -xFrom: | sed -e `'s/.*<//; s/>.*//'`"
procmail: No match on "fgrep -xi /home/user/var/mail/fromlist"
procmail: Non-zero exitcode (127) from "fgrep"
procmail: Notified comsat: "user@0:/home/user/var/mail/reginbox/msg.XXX"
procmail: Opening "/home/user/var/mail/reginbox/msg.XXX"
```

It looks as if formail cannot quite extract the lines where "From:" is located, which means that the email addresses in those lines are not carved out of the rest by the SED command and are not compared against the text file with the list of emails (fromlist), that's why the log show a "No match" message.

How can I find out where these things break down?

Comment: We can't really guess what's in your `mailstat` script, but I'm guessing it either has the error I outline in my reply, or else you mucked with the `PATH` variable so it cannot find the commands it needs.

Comment: Mailstat parses procmail logs and displays a summary about the messages (total and average size & no. of messages) delivered to all folders.

Comment: But the error messages seem to come from within that; the Procmail recipe you posted doesn't even contain a `grep` command.

Comment: @tripleee I have tried your suggestion (formail -rtzxTo:). Also, I have changed the second bit into <<grep -EiEio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b'>> so that FROMLS is now `formail -rtzxTo: | grep -EiEio '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b'`. The two commands work if run individually on the command line but they don't seem to work if piped into one another. Still FROMLS does not get assigned to anything, as show in the above log, hence the "No Match". How can I get FROMLS assigned to something?

Comment: The `grep` should not be necessary at all. Are you supplying the same flags repeatedly for humor or do you imagine this has some effect? `\b` is not supported in most `grep` dialects. But just dropping the `grep` completely will obviously also get rid of these errors. The correct code is already posted in my answer with an explanation of how it works.

Comment: You also find the same code in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512756/procmail-to-automatically-make-new-folders-to-store-emails-from-new-senders) where the variable is however called `Who`

Comment: Ok, let's see. I got rid of the grep command. The variable FROMLS is assigned to something and this brings my procmail control file to finally perform a comparison between the extracted email address and the external list of addresses. The problem though is that (still) the log file tells me that there is a mismatch. Unless you think I find humorous this too, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: by the way: the external list contains exactly the same email addresses that have been extracted, so there is no reason for a mismatch.

Comment: Are you sure? A common beginner error is to edit files on Windows and upload them with incorrect line endings. Try `cat -v` on the file and make sure there are no `^M` characters before the line endings. (If there are, google `dos2unix`.)

Comment: Working from a ubuntu OS so no such problems. This beginner salute you, I'm out.

Comment: No offense; I am unable to repro your problem with the information you have provided. I have updated my answer with a quick demo; perhaps you can try to reproduce the same on your end, and perhaps spot something which you are doing differently.

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edit. (The text is still available from the [revision history.)](/posts/50889697/revisions) If you have a new question, please create a new, self-contained post. (Linking back here for context is fine, and even encouraged; the post's title is a copyable link; or use the "share" link below the question.) Perhaps consider marking my answer as accepted; or post one of your own, and accept that. Accepting an answer marks this question as resolved so new readers don't waste time on analyzing problems which no longer are problems.

Comment: ... But your simple problem is that the file you created is not a valid folder. Messages in an mbox file are separated by the six characters (newline) F r o m (space) though you can instruct `formail` to do approximate heuristic splitting e.g. on apparent sequences of headers with `-d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for running an external command is

```
VARIABLE=`command to run`
```

You are missing the opening backtick, so you are running effectively

```
FROMLS="formail"
-xFrom: | sed etc is a syntax error
```

Anyway, the recipe to extract the sender is a bit inexact, because it doesn't cope correctly with various variations in email address formats.  A more robust but slightly harder to understand solution is

```
FROMLS=`formail -rtzxTo:`
```

which makes `formail` generate a reply `-rt`, then *from the generated reply* extract the `To:` address, which of course now points back to the original sender. By design, `formail` only puts the actual email address of the sender of the input message in the `To:` header when it generates the reply, so that's what you will be extracting.

With that out of the way, your script should technically work to the point where it can extract the matching messages and copy them to the destination folder you want.  Here's a quick demo:

```
tripleee$ cd /tmp

tripleee$ echo moo@example.com >fromlist

tripleee$ cat one.rc
# temporary hack
SHELL=/bin/sh
MAILDIR=/tmp
MAIL=.
VERBOSE=yes

FROMFL=$MAIL/fromlist

FROMLS=`formail -rtzxTo:`

:0
* ? fgrep -xi "$FROMLS" "$FROMFL"
$MAIL/inbox


tripleee$ procmail -m one.rc <<\:
From: ick@example.com
To: poo@example.org
Subject: no match

hello
:
procmail: [16406] Wed Jun 27 13:41:35 2018
procmail: Assigning "FROMFL=./fromlist"
procmail: Executing "formail,-rtzxTo:"
procmail: Assigning "FROMLS=ick@example.com"
procmail: Executing "fgrep,-xi,ick@example.com,./fromlist"
procmail: Non-zero exitcode (1) from "fgrep"
procmail: No match on "fgrep -xi ick@example.com ./fromlist"
 Subject: no match
  Folder: **Bounced**                                                        61

tripleee$ procmail -m one.rc <<\:
From: moo@example.com
To: poo@example.org
Subject: match

hello
:
procmail: [16410] Wed Jun 27 13:41:37 2018
procmail: Assigning "FROMFL=./fromlist"
procmail: Executing "formail,-rtzxTo:"
procmail: Assigning "FROMLS=moo@example.com"
procmail: Executing "fgrep,-xi,moo@example.com,./fromlist"
procmail: Match on "fgrep -xi moo@example.com ./fromlist"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=./inbox"
procmail: Opening "./inbox"
procmail: Acquiring kernel-lock
 Subject: match
  Folder: ./inbox                                                            68
```

There is no way really for `procmail` to remove anything from the input folder.  If you want to do that, a common solution is to have Procmail write the non-matching messages to another output folder, then copy that back over the input file. The net effect is that the messages from the original input folder are now partitioned into two files, one with matching, and one with non-matching messages.

Comment: In response to your answer about how to run an external command, I have to say that the missing opening backtick is where it should be in procmail control file and I am not quite sure why I missed to type it into the question, since I copied an pasted the command as it is from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about using those flags and to extract emails from the "To:" header as opposed to the "From:" one. I will address this immediately.

Comment: Currently, I launch a script which calls procmail to process the input file ("/var/mail/mario"), previously retrieved by fetchmail. In this script, I have "cat mario >> .newfile" and "formail -s procmail < .newfile". Procmail filters .newfile against fromlist ("FROMFL=$MAIL/FROMLIST"), and the sed command "cleans up" all that is not an email address from inside "mario", so that the fgrep command can compare the two and try to find a match. Is that what you are trying to outline in your last paragraph of your answer?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what it describes.

Comment: (Notice the tightened-up quoting in the demo snippet, though I don't think it makes a difference for the specific addresses you were testing with.)